# Installation failed while installing pydoop using conda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I have anaconda installed on ubuntu, i am using spyder for python development
I am trying command

```
conda install -c ijstokes pydoop
```

it is giving:

```
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pydoop -> python 3.5* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - pydoop -> python 3.5* -> xz 5.0.5
  - python 3.6*
```

Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.
Dont know what to do next please help.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that there is a version conflict between `pydoop` which has a dependency on `python 3.5*` and `python 3.6*`. The easiest way to fix this is to make an environment with Python 3.5.

```
conda create -n py35 -c ijstokes python=3.5 pydoop
```

Answer (score 0):

This package for conda is fairly old. Why not try to install pydoop from pypi?

```sh
pip install pydoop
```